# getting warning Header may not contain more than a single header on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

I'm learning WordPress and PHP and building a website at www.sunriselodging.com

When trying to enter data in a form, I get a PHP error warning saying 'header may not contain more than a single header' on line 6. I've tried solutions like checking the URL which are not related to PHP. I read a few solutions here that are PHP dependent and hence I cannot figure out what needs to be done here.

My code is below:

```
    <?php

    $reservation_message = $_POST['reservation_message'];

    // Redirect back
Header('Location: '. $_POST['reservation-url'].'?message='.$reservation_message);
echo "<meta charset='utf-8'>";  

// Loading variables from form
$blog_name = $_POST['blog_name'];
$blog_email = $_POST['blog_email'];
$reservation_email_subject = $_POST['reservation_email_subject'];
$reservation_email = $_POST['reservation_email'];
$reservation_email_switch = $_POST['reservation_email_switch'];

$room = $_POST['reservation-room'];
$checkin = $_POST['reservation-checkin'];
$checkout = $_POST['reservation-checkout'];
$people = $_POST['reservation-people'];

$name = $_POST['reservation-name'];
$email = $_POST['reservation-email'];
$phone = $_POST['reservation-phone'];
$message = $_POST['reservation-message'];

if($reservation_email_switch == 'on'){
    // EMAIL TO CLIENT
    // SET info to email
        // From in format NAME <email>
        $from = $blog_name.'<'.$blog_email.'>';

        // Reply to in format NAME <email>
        $reply = $blog_name.'<'.$blog_email.'>';

        // Subject
        $subject = $reservation_email_subject;

        // Message
        $message = $reservation_email;
    //

    $to = $email;
    $headers = 'From: '. $from . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: '. $reply . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    // Send mail
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    // END OF EMAIL TO CLIENT
    // ---------------------
}

// EMAIL TO RESERVATION CREW
$message = $_POST['reservation-message'];
$headers = 'From: '. $name . '<' . $email . '>' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '. $name . '<' . $email . '>' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$subject = 'Reservation for room #' . $room;
$message = 'Name: ' . $name . '
Room: #' . $room . '

Check in: ' . $checkin . '
Check out: ' . $checkout . '
Number of people: ' . $people . '

Email: ' . $email . '
Phone: ' . $phone . '

' . $message;

$to = $blog_email;

// Send mail
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
// END OF EMAIL TO RESERVATION CREW
// ---------------------

exit();

?>
```

The URL for the form is here - http://www.sunriselodging.com/reservation/. Apparently the form hasn't been sending emails either. Can someone please look at this and advise what's wrong with the code here?

I'll also appreciate if someone can direct me towards a good online PHP course for beginners (great if free).

Thank You,

Aadi

Comment: any code after Header location, is not going to run

Comment: @aadi code after header does run. You should always put and exit() or die() after a header to prevent further code execution.

Comment: thanks for responding. I'm completely new to PHP and cannot figure out the solution. can you please tell me what can I do with the code to make it work?

Comment: @aadi http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php you should ad 'exit;' after your header. Not sure that it matters but i think 'Header' should be lower.

Comment: thanks @bassxzero, I tried adding both exit(); and exit; and now it gives an "(T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)' error. What should I do?

Comment: @aadi can you update your code and submit a picture of the error with the line number?

Comment: Sure @bassxzero. Here's the [edit I made](http://imgur.com/rfkzmcS)
and here's the [error](http://imgur.com/YQ58ZSw). The error is still on line 6

Comment: In your image ( line 6 after "-url']"  ) you have '.'?message it should be .'?message

Comment: @bassxzero I did as you [suggested](http://imgur.com/9TnTdQV) and now there's an [error](http://imgur.com/U0cAf5F) on line 7. Sorry to be bothering, I can give you FTP access if you want to take a look at the code yourself.

Comment: @aadi change line 6 to this header('Location: ' . $_POST['reservation-url'] . '?message=' . $reservation_message );

Comment: no joy @bassxzero. I [tried](http://imgur.com/Y8ROFC6) with and without using the exit; string as well, but it throws the original [error](http://imgur.com/oo5uDC5) again.

Comment: @aadi This error is because there is a new line char in your php file that gets set to the output buffer. To solve all these problems you are having I would look into using ob_start(); with sessions and header redirect.

Comment: Where are you putting this code??

Comment: @Rasclatt it's on a form on a Wordpress website here http://www.sunriselodging.com/reservation/

Comment: thanks @bassxzero. I'll study these and try to figure out how to implement in my code

Comment: I know, not the site the code is on, but is this a plugin or on a template page or where?

Comment: yes, this is a Wordpress [template](http://demo-hotel.hotheme.co/) @Rasclatt. the form works on the demo website. I'm having problem with my installation. I've tried replacing the php file in question as well.

Comment: Is this code at the very top of your template page before everything?

Comment: it's on the very top of a php file called reservation.php. The file is stored in 'assets' sub-folders in the theme directory if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The whole problem with this here snippit is that you have 1) no conditions 2) no `mail()` function.

If you are going to use a header, you should probably have a condition. You should also probably have a condition to execute the emailer. Finally, you need to run this code before everything on the page (likely before the `get_header()` if on the page). Your workflow should go something similar to this:

```
<?php
   // I assume you want the form to first process the email then forward
   // so you need to check that the form was submitted
   // Then check that the customer email is valid
   if(isset($_POST['reservation-email']) && filter_var($_POST['reservation-email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Loading variables from form
        $blog_name  = $_POST['blog_name'];
        $blog_email = $_POST['blog_email'];
        $reservation_email_subject = $_POST['reservation_email_subject'];
        $reservation_email = $_POST['reservation_email'];
        $reservation_email_switch = $_POST['reservation_email_switch'];

        $room       =   $_POST['reservation-room'];
        $checkin    =   $_POST['reservation-checkin'];
        $checkout   =   $_POST['reservation-checkout'];
        $people     =   $_POST['reservation-people'];

        $name       =   $_POST['reservation-name'];
        $email      =   $_POST['reservation-email'];
        $phone      =   $_POST['reservation-phone'];
        $message    =   $_POST['reservation-message'];

        // Company email
        $master     =   'my@email.address';
        // Use a from address
        $header     =   "From: $email"."\r\n";

        // Try mailing off the reservation to the hotel
        if(mail($master,'Reservation Request',$message,$header)) {
            // If success, send another email to the customer
            $header =   "From: no-reply@hotel.com"."\r\n";
            mail($email,'Reservation Confirmation',$message,$header);
            // What is the difference between this "reservation_message" and "reservation-message"??
            $reservation_message    =   $_POST['reservation_message'];
            // Redirect back
            header('Location: '.$_POST['reservation-url'].'?message='.$reservation_message);
            exit;
        }
        else {
            echo 'Sorry, your reservation failed. Please contact customer service for reservations.';
            exit;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: hey @Rasclatt thanks for the code. I replaced this with the code on my reservation.php file and it throws the same error, only this time on line 36 (where the header(location) is.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you edit your post and add from the very top of your page down maybe like 100 lines?

Comment: Also, is this page included into another page? That will effect this whole scenario.

Comment: Yes, the reservation.php file runs on the 'Reservation' page of the wordpress website. I've edited my original post to show the entire code in the reservation.php file.

I've posted the code for the 'Reservation' page [here](http://www.codeshare.io/E8ty0)

Comment: At the very top of the page, do you have spaces before the `<?php`? In your example you do.

Comment: There are no spaces before <?php in either of the files

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this after some research on Stack Overflow.

I added urlencode to the last string on the line containing header. I made:

```
Header('Location: '. $_POST['reservation-url'].'?message='.$reservation_message);
```

to look like this:

```
Header('Location: '. $_POST['reservation-url'].'?message='.urlencode($reservation_message));
```

To enable the mail function to send email I changed line 54 from

```
$headers = 'From: '. $name . '<' . $email . '>' . "\r\n" .
```

to this

```
$headers = 'From: Booking@hotel.com' . "\r\n" .
```

& line 70 from

```
$to = $blog_email;
```

to

```
$to = 'my@email.address';
```

Hope this will help anyone who's stuck in a situation similar to mine. A big THANK YOU to all the people who helped.